# android activity active after popup

Tags: android

I have an Activity A, and there is a button B in the view. If somebody presses B then I want a pop-up which can take some part of screen making the A invisible in that area but rest of A is visible and active. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Then you dont need a popup as it will always obscure what is lying beneath. You can try something with hiding and showing views with some views enabled and some disabled. You can use shadows as background to give it a popup effect.

Comment: post some sample UI, what I think is you can do it by using hide and show of views